# How can I pass three dots parameter to dplyr funs

Tags: r, dplyr

Assuming there’s a column in dataset named GROUP:

```
summ <- function(dataset, FUN = mean, …) {
    dataset <- dataset %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% summarise_each(funs(FUN)) %>% arrange(GROUP)
    data.frame(dataset)
}
dataset<- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), GROUP = c(1, 2, 2, 1)
summ(dataset, na.rm = TRUE)

  GROUP    a
1     1   NA
2     2  2.5
```

The desired behavior would be to pass the na.rm = TRUE parameter to the mean function to remove NAs before computing the result. The expected output is:

```
  GROUP    a
1     1    1
2     2  2.5
```

How could I pass the … parameter to funs? I’ve tried

```
summarise_each(funs(FUN(., …)))
```

and

```
FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
funs_(dots = substitute(FUN), args = list(...))
```

and

```
summarise_each(funs_(dots = FUN, args = list(…)))
```

This last example raises error 'Error in UseMethod("as.lazy_dots")'

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Thank you. I've added an example and tried the suggested answers. @Axeman, tried your answer but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your function, create a new function that is the `FUN` function that incorporates the dot-dot-dots:

```
summ <- function(dataset, FUN = mean, ...) {
    FUN2 = function(x){FUN(x,...)}
    dataset <- dataset %>% group_by(GROUP) %>% summarise_each(funs(FUN2)) %>% arrange(GROUP)
    data.frame(dataset)
}

> summ(dataset,na.rm=TRUE)
  GROUP   a
1     1 1.0
2     2 2.5
> summ(dataset)
  GROUP   a
1     1  NA
2     2 2.5
>
```

Comment: Thank you, pretty neat solution. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the dots as a list, and using `substitute` we can use `funs_` properly:

```
summ <- function(dataset, FUN = mean, ...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  FUN <- substitute(FUN)

  dataset %>% 
    group_by(GROUP) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs_(FUN, args = dots)) %>% 
    arrange(GROUP)
}

summ(dataset, na.rm = TRUE)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 × 2
>   GROUP     a
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1   1.0
> 2     2   2.5
> ```